# canvas.getContext('2d'); error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am attempting to use this tutorial: http://html5gamedev.samlancashire.com/making-a-simple-html5-canvas-game-part-1-moving-a-sprite/

I have checked my code and it is exactly the same as the tutorial indicates (here it is: http://pastebin.com/1JsU28cx), however when ever I run the console gives me this error:"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null"

The error is in var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
I have seen a few similar questions, but they did not help...

I have no idea how to fix this...

Thanks!

Edit: I forgot to id canvas in the html

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Did you make sure you gave your canvas an id of "canvas" in your HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can ascertain from your [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) only pastebin, you either don't have a `<canvas>`, or its id is not `"canvas"`. Make sure you change the id to `"canvas"`, otherwise the `document.getElementById` will return `null`:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
 
var mySprite = {
    x: 200,
    y: 200,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    speed: 200,
    color: '#c00'
};
 
var keysDown = {};
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
});
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
});
 
function update(mod) {
    if (37 in keysDown) {
        mySprite.x -= mySprite.speed * mod;
    }
    if (38 in keysDown) {
        mySprite.y -= mySprite.speed * mod;
    }
    if (39 in keysDown) {
        mySprite.x += mySprite.speed * mod;
    }
    if (40 in keysDown) {
        mySprite.y += mySprite.speed * mod;
    }
}
 
function render() {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = mySprite.color;
    ctx.fillRect(mySprite.x, mySprite.y, mySprite.width, mySprite.height);
}
 
function run() {
    update((Date.now() - time) / 1000);
    render();
    time = Date.now();
}
 
var time = Date.now();
setInterval(run, 10);
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    // space and arrow keys
    if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: @Raven. Welcome to Stackoverflow!  If this answers your question, you should click the checkmark next to this question. This checkmark takes your question off the "unanswered" list. :-)

Comment: @markE Yes, I would have sooner but it has a fifteen minute or so time limit on selecting an answer, I'm not sure why...